# Como puedo pasar una variable con datos de entrada a un comando de ejecución?

Tags: linux, aws, shell-script

Estoy creando un Shell script en Linux, en el cual el usuario ingresa 3 datos de entrada y los paso como variable a 3 comandos de ejecución, pero aun no funciona

````
read -p 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ' ACCESS_KEY_ID
read -p 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=: ' SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
read -p 'AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=: ' TOKEN
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$ACCESS_KEY_ID
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$TOKEN ```

Alguna idea de como debo de pasar las variables?
````

Comment: ¿Pasar las variables adónde? ¿Cómo lo ejecutas?

Comment: Cada vez que ejecuto el comando export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, me pide una entrada necesito que esa entrada sea lo que ingrese el usuario aqui `read -p 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ' ACCESS_KEY_ID`

Comment: ¿Pero cuál es el contexto en el que haces esto? Si ejecutas el script, estas variables solamente estarán disponibles durante su ejecución. Si lo que quieres es que sus valores estén a disposición de la misma shell donde estás, debes hacer `source <el_script>`.

Comment: Mi idea es que en el mismo script se ejecuten los comandos `export ` tomando los datos de entrada a partir de las variables, no se si esto sea posible, ¿que opinas?

Comment: Opino que necesito más datos para opinar :) Estás mostrando solamente un pedacito de tu problema. Dale a [edit] para dar más detalles: cuál es tu objetivo final, cómo ejecutas todo el pipeline, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tengo el script `test.sh` con el siguiente contenido:

```
read -p 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ' ACCESS_KEY_ID
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$ACCESS_KEY_ID
env | grep -i aws
```

Al ejecutar el script estás exportando el contenido dentro de la shell o del proceso que está corriendo en ese proceso:

```
-> bash test.sh 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ThisIsATest
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ThisIsATest
```

Podrías ejecutarlo de la siguiente manera para exportarlas en el sistema:

```
$ -> . ./test.sh 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: Test
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=Test
$-> env | grep -i aws
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=Test
```